# Umbraco inline razor @section in head tag

Tags: asp.net, razor, umbraco

I'm trying to create razor @section in one of my views, using umbraco:Macro tag, in order to add scripts/styles specific for each view into head tag. 
My current code looks like this(head section of master page):

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderDefault" runat="server">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/foundation.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/responsiveslides.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/js.js"></script>

<umbraco:Macro runat="server" language="cshtml">
    @if(IsSectionDefined("JSIncludes"))
    {
        @RenderSection("JSIncludes")
    }
    @if(IsSectionDefined("CSSIncludes"))
    {
        @RenderSection("CSSIncludes")
    }
</umbraco:Macro>
</head>
```

and this(actual section in view):

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="ContentPlaceHolderDefault" runat="server">
<umbraco:Macro runat="server" language="cshtml">
    @section JSIncludes
    {
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main_page.js"></script>
    }
</umbraco:Macro>
```

But when i'm trying to open a page, i'm getting "Error loading MacroEngine script (file: )" error on top of my page.
Do anyone know the reason of this?
Would be great, if somebody knew how to add things like this properly.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason why you are using a razor macro for this? You can use ASP.NET `ContentPlaceHolder` to achieve this.

Comment: Ollie P, can you, please, tell me a bit more on how to use ContentPlaceHolder? I've never had an expirience with pure asp.net, so can't find anything on "Non-razor" syntax and classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a razor macro to add page-specific script references, use a `ContentPlaceHolder`

Master page:

```
<head>   
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PageScripts" runat="server" />
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PageStyles" runat="server" />
```

Content page:

```
<asp:Content ID="PageScript" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageScripts">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main_page.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.contentplaceholder.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot, you've realy helped.